# How to get diff of a file whose path has changed between two different commits?

Tags: git, github

My aim is here to cherry-pick an old commit from one of the branches to the master branch but since the path of the file has changed in the master branch i am unable to do that.

I have a file in a commit(lets say commit A(old_branch)) whose path is "src/path1/file.py" and i have the master branch in which now the same files path has changed to "src/path2/file.py". How can i get the diff of changes between the master and the old commit for this file so that i can apply the diff to the master directly?

I know i can manually do the changes in the concerned file and then commit, but i am keeping that as a last option.

Thanks

Comment: Sometimes `git cherry-pick` *can* pick changes across a rename. Git just needs to view the file as "renamed" when it compares the merge base (which, for a cherry pick, is the parent of the commit-to-pick) to the current commit. As long as there's no other file named `src/path1/file.py`, the delete-and-add can become rename if the contents of `src/path2/file.py` are similar enough. The default similarity threshold is 50% but you can use `-X find-renames=<number>` to change this.

Answer (score 2):

You can build a diff for a single pair of files, by using the `commit:path` notation :

```
git diff -p oldcommit:src/path1/file.py newcommit:src/path2/file.py > file.patch
```

You can then apply this patch by using directly the `patch` utility :

```
patch src/path2/file.py file.patch
```

`patch` is installed by default on linux systems, and is available from "git bash" on Windows systems.

---

Another way is to edit the paths in the generated patch, then apply the patch using `git apply` :

- edit the generated patch
- modify the file path in the leading block :

  ```
  # from :
  --- a/src/path1/file.py
  +++ b/src/path2/file.py

  # to :
  --- a/src/path2/file.py
  +++ b/src/path2/file.py
  ```
- apply the modified patch with git

  ```
  git apply file.patch
  ```